# Control Communications between dissimilar IP addresses

Tags: routing

I have new equipment arriving (and more to come) that is PLC controlled and uses Ethernet I/O. It may utilize up to 50 IP addresses that are not compatible with our LAN. I need to access only the PLC and HMI via our LAN. I have an HP 1910-8 switch. Can I configure this switch to accept communications compatible with our LAN and convert/route them to the PLC and HMI and in turn route PLC and HMI communications back to our LAN? In other words, could I configure the switch to route communications between a device with 10.39.122.22 IP address and a PLC whose address is 120.30.16.20? Possible or am I just being silly?

Comment: Surely you can change the IP addresses of your new equipment?

Comment: According to the datasheet that box does static routing. Check the manual?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could configure a VLAN, VLAN interface. and and static routing on this platform based on this document [How To Configure Layer 3 Static Routes & VLANs On HP v1910 24G](http://vmfocus.com/2012/09/26/how-to-configure-layer-3-static-routes-vlans-on-hp-v1910-24g/)

The devices, which have the same abilities, could perform inter-VLAN routing, which you need; just try from its GUI :

- create 2 VLANs
- create interface IP addresses for each
- assign ports in each VLAN
- try to ping from one to the other